# Remove class on hover

Tags: hover, removeclass, toggleclass

I have a horizontal accordion built purely in CSS. The closed accordion items each have a graphic icon and text wrapped in a P class.

I need the P class to be removed on ALL of the accordion items when the mouse hovers over a single accordion item.

What am I missing here?!

Thanks in advance!

Here's a link to the working horizontal accordion:
robertrhu.net/vail/tier2.html

Here is the code I'm trying to make work to no avail..

**Javascript:**

```
$("li.horizontal-accordion-item").hover(function () {
$(this).children("p").toggleClass("horizontal-accordion-resort-name"); });
```

**HTML**

```
<!--HOME POSTS SLIDER HEADING-->
    <h1
        class="horizontal-accordion-main-heading hide-for-medium show-for-small">
        Explore Our Resorts
    </h1>
<!--END HOME POSTS SLIDER HEADING-->

<div
    class="horizontal-accordion hide-for-small show-for-medium">

  <ul
       class="horizontal-accordion-wrapper">

     <li
         class="horizontal-accordion-item">

        <div
            class="icon-container"> 
            <img
               src="assets/img/vail-logo-icon.png"
               class="horizontal-accordion-resort-icon" />
        </div>

        <p
            class="horizontal-accordion-resort-name">
            Vail   
        </p>

        <a
          href="#"
          class="horizontal-accordion-title">                  
       </a>

      <div
         class="horizontal-accordion-content small-up-2">

         <!--POST FEATURED IMAGE FLOATED LEFT-->
         <div
           id="resorts-image-container"
           class="column">

        <img
           src="assets/img/explore-resorts-vertical-sample-photo.jpg"
           class="resort-post-image" />
      </div>

    <!--END POST FEATURED IMAGE FLOATED LEFT-->
       <div
          id="resorts-content-container"
          class="column">
       <img
         src="assets/img/resort-logo-small-park-city.gif"
        class="resort-logo" />

       <h3
         class="resort-slider-heading">
         Explore the largest resort in the U.S.   
       </h3>

       <!--POST EXCERPT-->   
        <p
          class="post-excerpt">
          Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.     Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec     ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra     augue.
       </p>
       <!--END POST EXCERPT FLOATED RIGHT-->

       <!--POST CTA BUTTON-->
       <a
         href="#"
         class="button">
         Button CTA
      </a>
      <!--END POST CTA BUTTON-->

       </div>  
     </div>
    </li>      
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("p").toggleClass("icon-container");
 });
```

You want to apply the toggleClass to the child "p" elements of "this" (the current li).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Implemented this edit and still no dice removing the class. Although I realize in my original code I was toggling the wrong class. I'm not wanting to toggle the "icon-container" but rather the "p.horizontal-accordion-resort-name". Here's the edit I made. Got it to do something but not what I want it to do.

$("li.horizontal-accordion-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("p").toggleClass("horizontal-accordion-resort-name");
 });

Here's a link to the page where you can see the result: robertrhu.net/vail/tier2.html

Comment: This appears to be toggling the resort name of the li I hover over. Its then adding it into the container when it opens. I need to remove the p.horizontal-accordion-resort-name from the surrounding li's, inside the other accordion items when an li.horizontal-accordion-item is hovered over. Then once mouse is removed have the p.horizontal-accordion-resort-name class put back in place. Right direction! Still stumped. My javascript chops are not up to snuff. :P Thanks a million for the help!

Comment: If you want to make all of the p elements disappear when you hover over the list item, try this: 
[code]
    $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().children("li").children("p").toggleClass("horizontal-accordion-resort-name");
 });
[/code]

Comment: OK! We're getting close. Thank you SO MUCH! I changed your code to a fadeOut instead of toggle. The toggle was messing with the layout. Here's the changed code:

Comment: $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").mouseout(function () { $(this).parent().children("li").children("p").fadeIn("horizontal-accordion-resort-name"); });

Comment: This permanently removes the resort names. So now I need to bring them back on mouseout. Here's my thinking, although its not working:

Comment: $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").mouseout(function () { $(this).parent().children("li").children("p").fadeIn("horizontal-accordion-resort-name"); });

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong code in for the mouseenter. Trying this instead of hover:

$("li.horizontal-accordion-item").mouseenter(function () { $(this).parent().children("li").children("p").fadeOut("horizontal-accordion-resor‌​t-name"); });

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... looked again, I think you want to do more than toggle a style.  If you want to show / hide the p element with that horizontal-accordion-resort-name, try this:

```
  $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("p.horizontal-accordion-resort-name").hide();
 });
    $("li.horizontal-accordion-item").blur(function () {
    $(this).children("p.horizontal-accordion-resort-name").show();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks again for the response and help! So, this is getting closer. It is causing the resort name to be removed from the accordion item that is hovered over, permanently removing it. The resort name does not come back when removing the hover, and it does not remove the resort name from the other accordion items. Here's the link with it in action: robertrhu.net/vail/tier2.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thanks a million for your guidance and outright code writing!

Just need to tweak the fade effect.

```
$("li.horizontal-accordion-item").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).parent().children("li").children("p").fadeOut("horizontal-accordion-resort-name"); });

$("ul.horizontal-accordion-wrapper").mouseleave(function () {
$(this).children("li").children("p").fadeIn("horizontal-accordion-resot-name"); });
```